# Does setting a pointer to nullptr affect other pointers pointing to the same address?

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr

Consider the following function which erases a node from a binary search tree if the node has no children:

```
void erase_no_children(node* todel)
{
    //...
    if (todel->parent->left == todel) //if todel is left child
        todel->parent->left = nullptr;

    if (todel->parent->right == todel) //if todel is right child
        todel->parent->right = nullptr;

    delete todel;
}
```

Since `todel->parent->left == todel` that means that by setting `todel->parent->left` to `nullptr`, I'm just as well setting `todel` to `nullptr`. The compiler doesn't complain at all.

**Question:** Is this safe to do? Does it leak? Or is it undefined behaviour?

Comment: You're not setting `todel` to `nullptr`.

Comment: No, you aren't setting todel to nullptr. You're setting todel->parent->left to nullptr. From what's shown here, this is safe and no memory leaks are present.

Remember these are pointers. All they do is point at something. You can have 100 pointers that point to the same memory, and setting one to nullptr doesn't affect the other 99.

Comment: Setting the value of `todel->parent->left` does not change the value of `todel`.

Comment: Reopening, because while the OP's question is already answered in the duplicate mark, there is a fundamental misunderstanding here that needs to be answered.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Thanks for that.  I was just about to when you did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Since `todel->parent->left == todel` that means that by setting `todel->parent->left` to `nullptr`, I'm just as well setting `todel` to `nullptr`.

That's not correct. `todel` and `todel->parent->left` are distinct pointer variables; setting one to `nullptr` doesn't affect the other.

So you're not deleting `nullptr` (which would be safe and a no-op).

Comment: I see. So I suppose I got the root of the problem wrong! Changed the title accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

Your function is making sure that your node can't be reached (i.e. making it an orphan) so that it is safe to delete its memory.  Your assignment of the Right & Left values to `nullptr` is perfectly acceptable, as it's stating that the node is no longer a child of its parent.

You are freeing the memory that was allocated to the C++ program by writing `delete todel`.  This can only occur the one time.  Once you've released the memory back to the OS, any further pointers to that variable are now "Stale" (i.e: out of date)

You are doing the correct thing in managing each pointer individually (tying off loose ends) and then deleting the remaining pointer.

Setting `todel->parent->left = nullptr` does not affect the pointer value contained in `todel`.  It also does not release the memory that was allocated from the OS to `todel`.  Your delete statement does; all of your assignments to `nullptr` are doing are removing other references to that memory.

Answer (score 1):

`todel->parent->left` and `todel->parent->right` are different pointers to `todel`.  If they are pointing at the same object as `todel` is, then it is **good practice** to reset them to point to null.  If you leave them set, you then have 'dangling pointers' which can cause problems that are notoriously hard to debug.

Note in particular that `delete todel;` means "I have finished with the object that `todel` points at."  That might not be true if there's still some other variable pointing at that object!